# Rails 4 memory profiling

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rspec, ruby-on-rails-4

I need to profile the memory usage of a rails 4 application (using ruby MRI). A little bit of googling made me step into http://guides.rubyonrails.org/v3.2.13/performance_testing.html

I have two questions :

- Is it compatible with rails 4
- I am using rspec. It seems that my `rake test` tasts are not available (neither `rails generator performance_test`). When I type `rake test:profile` for instance, I receive `Don't know how to build task 'test:profile'`. Does anybody know how to fix this ?

Thanks in advance for your help.

Comment: if you are using MRI 2.1.0 - there is https://github.com/samsaffron/memory_profiler - i am not familiar with the test:profile or performance_test referenced above

Comment: Unfortunately, I am using MRI 2.0. Is your gem compatible ?

Comment: that tool is 2.1 only

Comment: Did you find out how to do profiling with Ruby 4? Information seems obscure.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[Oink](https://github.com/noahd1/oink) is something I use with Rails 4.

> Oink adds memory and active record instantiation information to rails
>   log during runtime and provides an executable to help digest the
>   enhanced logs.
>
> Given a minimum threshold and a metric (memory or active record
>   instantiation), the oink executable reports:
>
> The top ten single requests which exceeded the threshold for the
>   metric, ordered by the request which exceeded the threshold the most
>
> The number of times each action exceeded the threshold for the metric,
>   ordered by the action which exceeded the threshold the most
>
> (in verbose mode) The log lines produced by requests which exceeded
>   the threshold

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure if it will work with MRI 2.1.0 but when I worked at Engine Yard will always recommended this tool:

[Binary Logic's Memory Logic](https://github.com/binarylogic/memorylogic)

One big warning about it though.  It logs performance so you only want to do this in development or on a test server.  ***Do not put it in to production*** or your application will grind to a halt.  Hope this helps.

Mike Riley