# What happens when Heroku runs out of memory?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, heroku

I've been getting heroku low-memory errors for a Ruby on Rails app. What exactly happens if this occurs?

Comment: https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/error-codes#r14-memory-quota-exceeded

Answer (score 8):

First, you'll receive an R14 error, warning you about exceeding the memory quota for your application. You'll likely see your application starting to grind down to a halt.

> **R14 - Memory quota exceeded**
>
> A dyno requires memory in excess of its quota (512MB on 1X dynos, 1024MB on 2X dynos, 6GB on PX dynos). If this error occurs, the dyno will page to swap space to continue running, which may cause degraded process performance.

https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/error-codes#r14-memory-quota-exceeded

If your application continues to consume more memory beyond this point, you'll receive an R15 error, and your application will be killed.

> **R15 - Memory quota vastly exceeded**
>
> A dyno requires vastly more memory than its quota and is consuming excessive swap space. If this error occurs, the dyno will be killed by the platform.

https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/error-codes#r15-memory-quota-vastly-exceeded

Note that it says *killed*, which means your application will most likely be offline at this moment and until you take further action.

Comment: Thanks! Silly question, but anything I can do about it beyond just increasing the number of dynos?

Comment: I would start by checking if there are any known issues with memory leaks in the web server you're using, either on it's own or when paired with your Heroku stack. Then you could move on to do some profiling of your application, to see if there are any optimizations that would be worthwhile. Here's a previous answer that could get you started: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22101737/rails-4-memory-profiling

Comment: Love that, definitely going to attempt profiling. How does memory work in the server? If a request takes up 500kb of memory and lasts 3 seconds, then at the end of the request, we get out memory back, right? At that rate, 300mb of memory should be enough for 600 simultaneous requests. Why am I getting errors at 2 - 3 simultaneous requests?

Comment: It depends what server you are using. If you are using Unicorn, for example, each worker you start up will consume at least a couple 100Mb of RAM. This is because each is a separate process, which has other benefits that can justify the hefty memory usage.

Comment: I tried to simulate this myself. You can directly get an R15 error without first getting R14, if the memory usage is too large. After an R15, the container is killed and restarted automatically. Only tried this once, so I'm not sure if it will keep restarting forever.